# Github Branches

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a project I'm working on and am hiring contractors to help me on certain parts of the code. The catch is that I don't want any one of the contractors to see all of it.

Is there a way on GitHub that I can assign them a branch under a private repository? Will this require the command line or can I do it on the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using submodules?

> Git's submodule support allows a repository to contain, as a subdirectory, a checkout of an external project.

More:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with [submodules](http://github.com/guides/developing-with-submodules).